# javascript growth optimisation

Tags: javascript, optimization

I need a more efficient way to increment a value by 0.0001 for every 1 in a parsed number. like the code quoted below but something that won't cause a browser to crash if you enter a too large number.

```js
function example(amm) {
    var base = 1;
    var ret = 0;
     
    for(var i=1; i<=amm; i++) {
     base += 0.0001;
        ret += base;
    }
    return [base,ret];
};

var total = example(100);
console.log(total[0].toFixed(4));
console.log(total[1].toFixed(4));
```

update: i need ret and base to be returned

Comment: This is just arithmetic. Looks quite a bit like `ret + base * num + 0.0001 * num * (num/2)` or something like that.

Comment: `amm * 0.0001 + 1` should be the same

Comment: @torazaburo You're right about arithemetic, but wrong in the expression, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some analysis, your function can be reduced to this:

```js
function example(amm) {
  var base = 1 + amm*0.0001;
  var ret = amm + 0.0001 * (amm)*(amm + 1)/2;
  return [base.toFixed(4), ret.toFixed(4)];
}
console.log(example(100));
console.log(example(200));
console.log(example(1000));
console.log(example(2000));
```

Why?

```
base = 1
ret = 0
for(var i=1; i<=amm; i++) {
        base += 0.0001;
        ret += base;
}
now, the above is just:
    base = 1 + amm*0.0001 // it sums 0.0001 amm times and has an initial value of 1
    ret = 1 + (1.0001) + (2.0002) + (3.0003) + (4.0004) + ... + (amm + 0.0001*amm)
        = 1*amm + 0.0001*((amm)*(amm + 1)/2)
        = amm + 0.0001*((amm)*(amm + 1)/2)
```

Some tests:

```js
function example1(amm) {
  var base = 1;
  var ret = 0;
  for(var i=1; i<=amm; i++) {
    base += 0.0001;
    ret += base;
 }
  return [base.toFixed(4), ret.toFixed(4)];
}
function example2(amm) {
  var base = 1 + amm*0.0001;
  var ret = amm + 0.0001 * (amm)*(amm + 1)/2;
  return [base.toFixed(4), ret.toFixed(4)];
}
console.log(example1(100) + ' === ' + example2(100));
console.log(example1(1564) + ' === ' + example2(1564));
console.log(example1(21343) + ' === ' + example2(21343));
console.log(example1(132) + ' === ' + example2(132));
console.log(example1(0) + ' === ' + example2(0));
console.log(example1(1) + ' === ' + example2(1));
```

Comment: The OP was also returning the base & ret in an array,.  So you could alter yours to do the same, with `return [1 + 0.0001 * amm, amm + 0.0001 * (amm)*(amm + 1)/2];`

Comment: @Keith I forgot that, but I updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a sequence.

> B(n) = B(n - 1) + 0.0001, n > 1
>
> B(0) = 1
>
> S(n) = S(n - 1) + B(n), n > 1
>
> S(1) = 0
>
> B(n) = (0.0001 * n) + 1
>
> S(n) = S(n - 1) + (0.0001 * n) + 1, n > 1
>
> S(1) = 0
>
> S(n) = 0.0001 * n * (n + 1) / 2 + n

Comment: @MrGeek thanks, I forgot that the first element is updated after the first 0.0001 was added. Nice catch, fixed.